# How to get allocated GPU spec in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab for deep learning and I'm aware that they randomly allocate GPU's to users. I'd like to be able to see which GPU I've been allocated in any given session. Is there a way to do this in Google Colab notebooks?

Note that I am using Tensorflow if that helps.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since you can run bash command in colab, just run `!nvidia-smi`:
[image]

Comment: > In Colab, you can invoke shell commands using either ! or %%shell.

Comment: How to use the information in python code? e.g., setting the batch_size accordingly?

Comment: @jerron I think that's worth a separate question as there are many ways to do that depending on your code :) If you're using PyTorch, you could use `torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory`

Comment: @Vladimir Sotnikov Thanks for the comment. I will create a separate question. btw, based on your answer I find following code works: `batch_size=int(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9+.5)*16
print(f'GPU mem:{int(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9+.5)}G, batch_size:{batch_size}')

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160588/how-to-set-batch-size-in-google-colab-notebook-according-to-allocated-node-spec

Answer (score 38):

This makes it easier to read

```
!nvidia-smi -L
```

Comment: Thanks! The output of `nvidia-smi` was convoluted. This is so much easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Run this two commands in collab

CUDA: Let's check that Nvidia CUDA drivers are already pre-installed and which version is it.

```
!/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version

!nvidia-smi
```