# How to set batch size in Google Colab notebook according to allocated node specs

Tags: pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

It is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299967/how-to-get-allocated-gpu-spec-in-google-colab/). @Vladimir Sotnikov 's answer gave insctruction to get the config information of the allocated colab node. He also showed how to get such information with pytorch and suggested a separate question for it. And here you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is from [Vladimir Sotnikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300019/7086220):

```
import torch
batch_size=int(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9+.5)*16
print(f'GPU mem:{int(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9+.5)}G, batch_size:{batch_size}')
```